# Why is Metro Bundler claiming that app.json does not exist?

Tags: react-native, metro-bundler

Please note that this is not the same as other questions posted here regarding missing modules.
Whether I run `npx react-native run-android` or `npx react-native start` in my app folder, it seems to be claiming that my app.json file is missing, but it is there in the base directory.

```
    error: Error: Unable to resolve module `./app.json` from `index.js`:
    None of these files exist:
      * app.json
      * app.json\index(.native|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (C:\rn\MyApp\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ModuleResolution.js:163:15)
    at ResolutionRequest.resolveDependency (C:\rn\MyApp\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ResolutionRequest.js:52:18)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (C:\rn\MyApp\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:287:16)
    at Object.resolve (C:\rn\MyApp\node_modules\metro\src\lib\transformHelpers.js:267:42)
    at C:\rn\MyApp\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:434:31
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at resolveDependencies (C:\rn\MyApp\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:431:18)
    at C:\rn\MyApp\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:275:33
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (C:\rn\MyApp\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:87:24)
```

[image: Base directory]

index.js

```
/**
 * @format
 */

import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

Comment: can you show whats inside index.js?

Comment: @HassanKandil Done

Comment: restart the metro server.

Comment: I have shut everything down and restarted several times. Same result.

Comment: It might be related to metro dependency in node-modules , try reinstalling it

Comment: @HassanKandil what are you suggesting reinstalling?

Comment: yes reinstall the node modules

Comment: In the end I saved my own code and assets separately, deleted everything, initiated a brand new project and reinserted my code and assets. It might have solved the problem, but since it does not answer the question as asked, I have not submitted this as an answer.

Comment: Would love to know if anyone was able to solve this same issue without initiating a brand new project.

Answer (score 2):

We had a similar issue an after trying to clear our cache in just about every way, a restart of the machine is what solved it for us.